# Setting up server for Google Apps?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, email, email-server, gmail

So I am currently running CentOS 6 and trying to figure out how to get Google Apps (gmail) to work. I am completely new to mail server software but have a general idea of how it works. What software do you guys recommend running on the server? What would I need to configure to get it to work?

Also I am using a DNS service (Rage4) and need to setup the PTR records. I know the record value, TTL and priority. However, it is also prompting me for a "name" (xxx.domain.com). What would I have to put there? Does this even matter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Google Apps is a **hosted** service, meaning that it doesn't require you to maintain any of your own infrastructure other than a DNS domain and an MX record, which your domain registrar can likely host for you.

To clarify further, the reason one chooses GApps is so that they **don't** need to run their own infrastructure. If, for some crazy reason, you do want to run your own infrastructure, you won't be using Google Apps.

Comment: Are you saying to get the e-mail part of Google Apps to work, I only need to setup the MX records?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okay its likely I am setting the records up wrong then. Because when I use their CheckMX tool I am receiving the following "Mail servers are either not specified or not reachable or refuse to accept mail for this domain.". Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Well, give us the domain name in question so we can check on things. Other than that, there's nothing we can do other than tell you to double and triple-check things and verify that the records are set up correctly.

Comment: How do these records look to you? http://imgur.com/Vum1CVQ

Comment: Unless you want your email addresses to be of the form user@mail.example.com, you need to remove the "mail." from the "Name" field of those records.

Comment: As mentioned in the close reason above, you really ought to do some research into how both SMTP and DNS work.

Comment: The DNS manager I am using doesn't use any blanks or @s as valid input. Is there anything else I can put in that field?

Comment: I definitely will, I'm new to this and hoping to learn as much as I can!

Comment: Put example.com in there. That is the domain these MX records are for. Perhaps try just ".".